# I want to change List〈EntityAnnotation〉to String Array

Tags: java, string, list, android-studio, google-cloud-vision

I want to Title act.
I'm japanese high school student.
so,about not good to English.
I making colect color game.
This game want to cloud vision response become can use if()with String.
So,I want how to Title act.
However, whatever the method is, it only needs to be able to compare with a response string.

```java
public class ninsiki extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String ANDROID_CERT_HEADER = "X-Android-Cert";
    private static final String ANDROID_PACKAGE_HEADER = "X-Android-Package";

    private static final int GALLERY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST = 0;
    private static final int GALLERY_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
    public static final int CAMERA_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST = 2;
    public static final int CAMERA_IMAGE_REQUEST = 3;

    private TextView ocrTextView;
    private TextView ocrLabelView;
    private ImageView ocrImageView;
     //List<String> mozi;
    String moji="";
    int a=0,j;
    Intent o=getIntent();
    int coun;
///

            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                for(a=0;a<=10;a++){
                    if(moji.equals("まいこ")){-①
                        Intent intent = new Intent(ninsiki.this, Zuuo.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }

                }
 ///

    private String convertResponseToString(BatchAnnotateImagesResponse response) {
        String message="";

        List<EntityAnnotation> ocrData = response.getResponses().get(0).getTextAnnotations();-②
        //mozi=response.getResponses().get(0).getTextAnnotations();
        if (ocrData != null) {
            message += ocrData.get(0).getDescription();
            moji+=ocrData.get(0).getDescription();
        } else {
            message += R.string.text_detection_error;
        }

        return message;
    }

}
```

①
Here I tried to compare with the response. But it failed.

②
I tried to make it available by doing Tostring here. But it failed.

Comment: You need to show us the code and explain what you want and what doesn't work right now. Without code, we can't help.

Comment: OK.Please wait.Thank you.

Comment: I pasted to important point.

Comment: You also need to explain what do you want do to and what went wrong when you tried. Just from this code alone I can't tell.

Comment: Now I have written the request and situation.